# Why would this not work in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, overriding, spree

I am having problems with modifying a function in spree. The function is called copy_price

The original version is something like this:

```
def copy_price
  if variant
    self.price = variant.price if price.nil?
    self.currency = variant.currency if currency.nil?
  end
end
```

which if I understand right will update the line_item's unit price only if the price is null, which I believe it shouldn't be inside the orders page (after the order is completed). 
I noticed that order changes if the master price is changed inside the admin section even after the order is complete.

So i thought that the copy_price function was to blame, but each time i try to modify it there is no change.
E.g.

```
def copy_price
  @price_run = true
   self.price = 30.00
end

def get_price_run
  if @price_run == true
    return "true"
  else
    return "false"
  end
end
```

and call get_price_run inside my view to print out if the price run was actually run. and It keeps outputting false. Does anyone know why that would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. The function copy_price is only called when the line item is first created (e.g. when you put it into the cart). So when I was trying to find out if it was called while looking at the admin orders page it was never getting called.